# How to customize a seaborn the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

I am trying to find guidance on how to control and customize the legend in Seaborn plots but I can not find any.

To make the issue more concrete I provide a reproducible example:

```
surveys_by_year_sex_long

    year    sex wgt
0   2001    F   36.221914
1   2001    M   36.481844
2   2002    F   34.016799
3   2002    M   37.589905

%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn

sn.factorplot(x = "year", y = "wgt", data = surveys_by_year_sex_long, hue = "sex", kind = "bar", legend_out = True,
             palette = sn.color_palette(palette = ["SteelBlue" , "Salmon"]), hue_order = ["M", "F"])
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Weight')
plt.title('Average Weight by Year and Sex')
```

[image]

In this example I would like to be able to define M as Male and F as Female and instead of sex to have Sex as title of the legend.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, to access the legend created by seaborn needs to be done via the seaborn call.

```
g = sns.factorplot(...)
legend = g._legend
```

This legend can then be manipulated,

```
legend.set_title("Sex")
for t, l in zip(legend.texts,("Male", "Female")):
    t.set_text(l)
```

The result is not totally pleasing because the strings in the legend are larger than previously, hence the legend would overlap the plot

[image]

One would hence also need to adjust the figure margins a bit,

```
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9,right=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note, this solution will work only for plotting functions that use Figure-level interface. For other functions, for example, `sns.boxplot()` the way around is to declare and call `matplotlib` axis object directly.

Answer (score 6):

I've always found changing labels in seaborn plots once they are created to be a bit tricky. The easiest solution seems to be to change the input data itself, by mapping the values and column names. You can create a new dataframe as follows, then use the same plot commands.

```
data = surveys_by_year_sex_long.rename(columns={'sex': 'Sex'})
data['Sex'] = data['Sex'].map({'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female'})
sn.factorplot(
    x = "year", y = "wgt", data = data, hue = "Sex",
    kind = "bar", legend_out = True,
    palette = sn.color_palette(palette = ["SteelBlue" , "Salmon"]),
    hue_order = ["Male", "Female"])
```

[image: Updated names]

Hopefully this does what you need. The potential problem is that if the dataset is large, creating a whole new dataframe in this manner adds some overhead.