# Changing legend labels on seaborn FacetGrid with barplot and boxplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, boxplot

How can you change the legend labels on a seaborn FacetGrid using barplots and boxplots?

With scatterplots, you can do this easily:

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time')
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='sex')
plt.legend(labels=['Men', 'Women'])
```

[image: Modifying legend labels for scatterplot works as expected]

However, the same code using boxplots removes the color patches from the legend:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time')
g.map_dataframe(sns.boxplot, x='smoker', y='tip', hue='sex')
plt.legend(labels=['Men', 'Women'])
```

[image]

Unlike barplot itself, the FacetGrid has no `legend_` property, so existing solutions for barplots like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475459/customise-seaborn-hue-legend-for-boxplot) don't easily apply.

How do you modify the legend labels without removing the color patches?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with FacetGrid's `add_legend` method. When calling `add_legend`, the `legend_data` parameter maps labels to color patches. FacetGrid stores its default legend data in a `_legend_data` property. So all you need to do is pass a `legend_data` parameter with your desired labels as the keys and the FacetGrid's default `_legend_data` values as the values.

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time')
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x='smoker', y='tip', hue='sex')
hue_labels = ['Men', 'Women']
g.add_legend(legend_data={
    key: value for key, value in zip(hue_labels, g._legend_data.values())
})
```

[image]

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time')
g.map_dataframe(sns.boxplot, x='smoker', y='tip', hue='sex')
hue_labels = ['Men', 'Women']
g.add_legend(legend_data={
    key: value for key, value in zip(hue_labels, g._legend_data.values())
})
```

[image]

Comment: Don't access `g._legend_data` in code that shouldn't unexpectedly break at some point when you update seaborn.